# Page redirecting again on login page due to footer html code in Laravel 4

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-4

I've created login and dashboard pages in laravel. Once user login, program takes user to dashboard page successfully but after 1-2 seconds it redirects again to login page (after refreshing the page). I found  this problem in my footer code in `default.blade.php` page. Whenever I add footer code its not working but whenever I add contents without foot, the code is working well. I know this is happening due to my footer code but I don't know why this happening due to simple html code and how do I fix this.
I've added my simple footer code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sjobe0uw/).

Comment: There's nothing in that HTML that could redirect the user. Your problem must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening due to lots of images are missing in HTML  code or you can say lots of images have wrong directory path.

Fixing the directory path so that the images are correctly resolved fixes the issue.